# Display Images in a ng smart table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

How to display images in a column in an ng smart table? We have a number of columns most of which are data and one column has image. As per the concept of ng smart table I wrote the following code which just shows an URL in place of the image as in the image.

[image: Actual Table View]

**home.component.html**

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="notifications"></ng2-smart-table>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { myListDB } from "../../../shared/tables/myList";


export class MyBookingsComponent implements OnInit {

  public pageTitle = "My Home Page";

  public notifications = [];

  constructor() {
    this.notifications = myListDB.data;
}

  public settings = {
      editable:false,
      actions: {
          position: 'right',
          add: false,
          edit: false,
          delete: false
      },
      columns: {
          no: {
              title: 'No'
          },          
          brandlogo: {
              title: 'Brand Logo',
          },
          brand: {
            title: 'Brand'
          },
          title: {
            title: 'Campaign Name'
          }
      },
  };

  ngOnInit(){

   }

}
```

**myList.ts**

```
export class myListDB {
    static data = [
      {
        no: 1,
        brandlogo: "assets/images/brands/brand1.jpg",
        brand: "ABC Company",
        title: "XYZ Campaign"
      }

]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this issue!

**home.component.ts** (Add a **'type: html'** to the **brandLogo** image array as in the code)

```
import { myListDB } from "../../../shared/tables/myList";


export class MyBookingsComponent implements OnInit {

  public pageTitle = "My Home Page";

  public notifications = [];

  constructor() {
    this.notifications = myListDB.data;
}

  public settings = {
      editable:false,
      actions: {
          position: 'right',
          add: false,
          edit: false,
          delete: false
      },
      columns: {
          no: {
              title: 'No'
          },          
          brandlogo: {
              title: 'Brand Logo',
              type: 'html'
          },
          brand: {
            title: 'Brand'
          },
          title: {
            title: 'Campaign Name'
          }
      },
  };

  ngOnInit(){

   }

}
```

**myList.ts** (Add **img** tag with the src specified as you write in HTML code)

```
export class myListDB {
    static data = [
      {
        no: 1,
        brandlogo: "<img src='assets/images/brands/brand1.jpg' class='imageClass'>",
        brand: "ABC Company",
        title: "XYZ Campaign"
      }

]
}
```

Now the expected result is as follows:

[image: Expected Table View]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom component

- First Create the component

## New component, to use as custom component, (image-thumbnail.column.ts)

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'image-thumbnail-column',
 template: `
   <div>
     <img [src]="value" />
   </div>
`,
})
export class ImageThumbnailColumn implements OnInit {
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() rowData: any;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.value);
    console.log(this.rowData);
}
}
```

- 2nd , add type:"custom" to the image column (column property)
- 3rd , add renderersComponent: ImageThumbnailComponent (not sure about its rendererComponent or whatever , see the documents  of smart table) to image column , it's important step , because , when you set the type of the column to custom , smart table will look into this property , to send information about table data to the component

## Updated Home component (home.component.ts)

```
import { myListDB } from "../../../shared/tables/myList";
import  { ImageThumbnailColumn } from "./image-thumbnail.column.ts";


export class MyBookingsComponent implements OnInit {

  public pageTitle = "My Home Page";

  public notifications = [];

  constructor() {
    this.notifications = myListDB.data;
}

  public settings = {
      editable:false,
      actions: {
          position: 'right',
          add: false,
          edit: false,
          delete: false
      },
      columns: {
          no: {
              title: 'No'
          },          
          brandlogo: {
              title: 'Brand Logo',
              type: 'custom',
              renderComponent: ImageThumbnailColumn
          },
          brand: {
            title: 'Brand'
          },
          title: {
            title: 'Campaign Name'
          }
      },
  };

  ngOnInit(){

   }

}
```

- 4th , smart table will try to send two objects to your custom component , first one is value and the second one is rawData , inside the custom component , you need to use @Input() value: InterfaceOfValueForColumn;  and @Input() rawData: InterfaceOfEachRawData;
- Finalize, make sure to add the custom component to the entry components of the used module,

  for example , if the module that is used the smart table is home.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  entryComponents: [ImageThumbnailColumn],
  ...
})
export class HomePageModule {
}
```

in this situation , the value is type of string and contains the url that shows in your attached picture

then you can show those beautiful images any way you want.

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet? It will be helpful!

Comment: @BIJAY
Answer updated , base on the codes you shared :)